# Is it possible for modules to share code

Tags: vb.net, module

I am looking at Module A which performs task

1. I am also looking at another module (module B) which performs task
2. Tasks A & B are to all intents and purposes similar but for one
   small difference.

If they were classes I would be inclined to re-factor them such that the common code ended up in a base class inherited by modules A and B (which would of course now be classes because you cant inherit in a module).

However keeping Modules A & B as modules happens to be preferable in this particular instance so is there a clean way to have a third module that performs the same role as a base class or does one simply have to accept that in this instance there will have to be an element of code duplication.

I'm thinking along the lines of a friend declaration for the third module with the common methods declared as friends within that, but am wondering if I've overlooked something obvious.

Comment: Why is it preferable to keep the modules in this instance. It's not usually that much effort to just turn them into classes, even if they aren't the best designed ones ever seen.

Comment: There is no inheritance for modules, but, since modules are essentially the same thing as a class with all `Shared` members, you should be able to convert it to a `Shared` method of a class pretty painlessly.

Comment: Tony Converting the modules into classes would then involve having to create constructors everywhere that they are used amongst other things.  Refactoring them to have a common module with code that can be shared seems at this stage to be preferable and less prone to adding potential errors elsewhere.  Where I starting from scratch it would be classes.

Comment: It's hard to say what you should do since we can't see the code. There's a lot of different options. Maybe the easiest (not elegent) way could be to create a class with Shared functions. Sort of like a helper class. Both modules would use the same shared function to do their work.

Answer (score 1):

No, you haven't overlooked something obvious, I don't think.  You should always try to follow [the DRY principal (Do Not Repeat Yourself)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself); in this case, refactor it so the common code exists only once in a separate module, and only the code that is different between the two original modules is left in those two.